# How to add an item to a list

Tags: html

I am creating a website in HTML and have a form that asks for the users email to get weekly emails and I need help on how to collect all of the emails in one spot. I am a beginner coder.

this is my code for the form:

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
<form name="email">
<p>Enter your email to get weekly referee tips.</p>
Email<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="button" onclick="list" value="enter"/>
</div>
<script>
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
int listSize = list.size();
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i)
list.add("Email");
</script>
```

Comment: What type of script is that?

Comment: Oh nooo you're combining Java and Javascript!! `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Rick S like a place to store all of the emails so that i can use it later on

Comment: You should probably change the title of the question.

Comment: @JohnBupit the title of the list? and what should i change it to

Comment: [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: @nicael I was told that <script> is for javascript

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ how do i fix it?

Comment: @user3799153 `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` is not javascript.

Comment: @JohnBupit java is a programming language and javaScript is a scripting language. JavaScript can only be run on a browser.

Comment: @admdrew how do i make it into javaScript?

Comment: @user3799153: Umm... that's a link. I'm not asking the question. But, you should probably.

Comment: @user3799153 `java is a programming language and javaScript is a scripting language. JavaScript can only be run on a browser` Is wrong for a few reasons... `how do i make it into javaScript?` Write it correctly in javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your array size is 0 at first so that for loop never runs. Also, that is Java not Javascript. This would be the correct way to do so in Javascript:

```
var i;
var list = [];

for(i = 0 ; i < ??? ; i++) {
    list.push("email");
}
```

Comment: Why "???"? Change it to list.length.

Comment: `list.length` would be 0 so I'm not sure what this code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Heh, agree... Strange.

Comment: thanks @jongusmoe, so now will all of the emails be stored in one place?

Comment: @user3799153 The funny thing is they won't be. Because size (or length) of empty array is 0. So your loop won't work. It will be simply skipped.

Comment: @nicael cant you just change the size to like 15 so that it could hold a max of 15 emails?